# Is there a way to make a texture (not an object) always face the camera?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I know how to make an object always face a camera, but is there a way to make a texture on an object always face the camera, regardless of the orientation of the object? (specifically wanting one of two textures applied to an object to do this, as can use it to create a cool kind of portal effect).

Googling has come up with nothing, alas. Does anyone know how I might go about it?

Comment: have you tried the Texture Coordinate output called Camera?

Comment: You could look into the "Camera" Output of the Texture Coordinate Node. Alternatively use the "Object" Output and select an Empty in the TC Node. If you make that empty face the camera with a Track To Constraint (e.g.), it should have a similar effect, but with more control.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, cracked it about 5 mins after posting the question - attach a texture coordinate to a vector transform, set the latter to go from object to camera, then plug into mapping node and then the texture itself. Probably obvious in hindsight! thx to those who answered